# Aggregating across list of dataframes and storing all results

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a list of 9 data frames, each data frame having approx 100 rows and 5-6 cols.

I want to aggregate the values in a col based on the groups specified in another col across all data frames and store all results in a separate data frame. To elucidate, consider a list

```
    [[1]]  
    Date  Group  Age
    Nov     A    13
    Nov     A    14
    Nov     B    9
    Nov     D    10
    [[2]]
    Date  Group  Age
    Dec     C    11
    Dec     C    12
    Dec     E    10
```

My code is as follows

```
for (i in 1:length(list)){
x<-aggregate(list[[i]]$Age~list[[i]]$Group, list[[i]], sum)
x<-rbind(x)
}
```

But finally, x contains only the aggregate result from dataframe 2 (since i =2) and not that of dataframe 1, though I am trying to bind the results.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you are overwriting `x` when you repeat the loop. You should save your intermediate result (`x`) in an empty list that you initialize outside of the loop doing `new_list[[i]] <- x` then combine later. Or you could grow your result in the loop like `x <- aggregate...; z <- rbind(z, x)` (z should also be initialized outside of the loop as an empty data.frame)

Comment: It can be done without a `for`  loop. Use `lapply` to aggregate across your list, and do.call to `rbind` them: Something like: `do.call(rbind,lapply(list,function(x)aggregate(x$Age~x$Group,x, sum)))`

Answer (score 3):

In R, there are many efficiently implemented functions which help to avoid the hassle of writing `for` loops.

[In his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513776/aggregating-across-list-of-dataframes-and-storing-all-results#comment77989393_45513776), S Rivero has suggested to use `lapply()` instead of a `for` loop and to `rbind()` the aggregates later:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dflist, function(x) aggregate(Age ~ Group, x, sum)))
```

My suggestion is to combine the `data.frame`s first and then compute the aggregates using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(dflist)[, sum(Age), by = Group]
```

> ```
>    Group V1
> 1:     A 27
> 2:     B  9
> 3:     D 10
> 4:     C 23
> 5:     E 10
> ```

#### Data

```
dflist <- list(structure(list(Date = c("Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov"), Group = c("A", 
"A", "B", "D"), Age = c(13L, 14L, 9L, 10L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Group", "Age"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Date = c("Dec", "Dec", "Dec"), Group = c("C", 
    "C", "E"), Age = c(11L, 12L, 10L)), .Names = c("Date", "Group", 
    "Age"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))
```